Express JS - Understanding CSP?
I'm using Express, and having a CSP issue:
Refused to create a worker from 'blob:http://localhost:4000/bda8488f-14b5-4906-ab95-03f78146af69' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap:". Note that 'worker-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback. Note that '*' matches only URLs with network schemes ('http', 'https', 'ws', 'wss'), or URLs whose scheme matches `self`'s scheme. The scheme 'blob:' must be added explicitly.

My Simple App.js:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
     res.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "worker-src * blob:;  child-src blob: gap:;  img-src 'self' blob: data:;  default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: blob:");
     return next();
 });

app.use(express. Static('mobile'))
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`))

Where have i gone wrong?

The most likely explanation is that there are multiple CSP headers present. Your content needs to pass all of them, and adding another can only make the total policy stronger. You will need to identify where the other policy is set and remove/adjust that policy.
